# Error installing applications

Tags: apt, live-usb, dpkg

I've installed a Ubuntu live install with persistence mode on a USB stick using Linux Live USB creator. (Windows got corrupted while changing a .sys file, partition table was saved.)

I'm not able to install any programs or software (ex. Chrome, VLC, ) as well as some plugins (ex. Flash). I get this error message if I try to install anything.

```
Install these packages without verification? [y/N] y 
dpkg: error: unable to stat triggers deferred file `/var/lib/dpkg/triggers/Unincorp': Input/output error
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (2)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Which method of app installation method did you try?

I'm guessing that you tried the terminal way with the 'sudo apt-get install'.

Try the 'software center' , the 'synaptic package manager' or 'directly download the .deb file from manufactures website.

Sometimes persistence installs show up various problems. I got some errors when I used Lili usb live. Try various programs to create usb live. I use universal usb installer and boot into the usb.

Hope that helps. :) happy ubuntuing {**U**}

Comment: yes I am using 'sudo apt-get install' command.
Ok, I will surely try, thanks :-)